# Using Azure management Libraries for deploying a service. Error: "The given path's format is not supported."

Tags: azure

Here is the code which I am using for deploying a service in Azure,

```
  internal async static Task DeployCloudService(this SubscriptionCloudCredentials credentials)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var _computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Deploying a service...");
                    var storageConnectionString = await GetStorageAccountConnectionString(credentials);

                    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

                    var blobs = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                    var container = blobs.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["containerName"]);

                    if (!container.Exists()) { Console.WriteLine("Container not found"); };

                    await container.SetPermissionsAsync(
                        new BlobContainerPermissions()
                        {
                            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container
                        });

                    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(
                        Path.GetFileName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["packageFilePath"]));
                    var blob1 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(
                       Path.GetFileName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configFilePath"]));
                    await _computeManagementClient.Deployments.CreateAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceName"],
                            DeploymentSlot.Production,
                            new DeploymentCreateParameters
                            {
                                Label = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["label"],
                                Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceName"],
                                PackageUri = blob.Uri,
                                Configuration = File.ReadAllText((blob1.Uri).ToString()),
                                StartDeployment = true
                            });
                    Console.WriteLine("Deployment Done!!!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The Idea is that package and config file is already there in blobs within some container and I can deploy my service when I am using  `Configuration = File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configFilePath"])`(which takes the file from the local path and working fine as expected), but since I don't wanna do that I am trying to use the config file from Azure blobs, but `File.ReadAllText`is not taking the Uri of my file which I checked is fine and giving `System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}` with`base   {"The given path's format is not supported."}`.(as its looking for string parameter)

> My Question is that how can we use the config file (.cscfg) from the
>   server

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading blob's contents by using [`DownloadText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtext.aspx) method. Something like:

```
new DeploymentCreateParameters
                            {
                                Label = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["label"],
                                Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceName"],
                                PackageUri = blob.Uri,
                                Configuration = blob1.DownloadText(),
                                StartDeployment = true
                            });
```

Comment: There is nothing like `DownloadText()` method

Comment: Sure there is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtext.aspx

Comment: Then perhaps that's not the right way,anyway Thanks @Gaurav. If I got anything I'll comment.